# New ASP.NET MVC3 project does not compile in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, macos, mono, monodevelop

I tried installing MonoDevelop 3.0.5 and the MDK 3.0.1 (beta). MonoDevelop gives me the option to create a new ASP.NET MVC3 project. "Neat!", I thought. So I choose that, and try to run it to see what the default project gives me.

And MonoDevelop just errors out. Looking at the references, both `System.Web.Helpers` and `System.Web.WebPages` are displayed in red and it says `Assembly not available for Mono / .NET 4.0 (in Mono 3.0.1)`.

So what's going wrong :( It seems that if MonoDevelop offers me the option, it should Just Work™, right?

Comment: Good question - I've just come up against the same problem.  I have meebey's Mono 3.0.1 installed on Debian.

Comment: I remember that in the earlier versions, you had to copy the binaries to mono distribution yourself. This was before microsoft opensourced aps.net mvc and changed the license, Mono couldn't redistribute the dll's. Isn't this a similar problem with the beta?

Comment: Have you tried new xamarin Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in their buglist:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8516

Comment: Yep, because I submitted that bug :P